# Python django form processing and execution behavior skipping execution

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I am having some problems with processing my form in python django. There is some unusual behavior when processing the form. Below is my form and part of the function that processing the form in the view. I am fairly new to python and django, so any help will be much appreciated.

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
     pr_name = forms.CharField(label="Pr Name", max_length=64, required=False)
     org = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Org.objects.all(), required=False)
     group_name = forms.CharField(label="Unique Submission Name", max_length=64, required=False)
     group_ref = forms.CharField(label="Ref", max_length=12, required=False)
     group_url = forms.URLField(label="URL", required=False)

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            p_ids = []
            g_ids = []
            f_ids = []

        logging.debug('hello1')
        # Filter first
        firstQuery = 'SELECT * FROM pr where '
        pr_name = form.cleaned_data['pr_name']
        if pr_name:
            logging.debug('hello2')
            firstQuery += '(name like \'%' + pr_name + '%\')'
        else:
            pass

        logging.debug('hello3')
        org = form.cleaned_data['org']
        if org:
            org = Org.objects.get(name = org)
            org_id = org.id
            firstQuery += '(org_id = ' + str(org_id) + ')'
        else:
            pass

        firstQuery = firstQuery.replace(')(', ') AND (')
        logging.debug('First query: %s' % firstQuery)
        p_search_results = P.objects.raw(firstQuery)
        logging.debug('First query: %s' % p_search_results)
        for x in p_search_results:
            p_ids.append(x.id)
        logging.debug('p_ids: %s' % p_ids)


        # Filter Group
        secondQuery = 'SELECT * FROM group where '
                group_name = form.cleaned_data['group_name']
        if group_name:
            secondQuery += '(name like \'%' + group_name + '%\')'
        else:
            pass

        group_ref = form.cleaned_data['group_ref']
        if group_ref:
            secondQuery += '(ref like \'%' + group_ref + '%\')'
        else:
            pass

        group_url = form.cleaned_data['group_url']
        if group_url:
            secondQuery += '(method_url like \'%' + group_url + '%\')'
        else:
            pass

        secondQuery = secondQuery.replace(')(', ') AND (')
        logging.debug('Second query: %s' % secondQuery)
        group_search_results = PredictionGroup.objects.raw(secondQuery)
        logging.debug('Second query: %s' % group_search_results)
        for x in group_search_results:
            g_ids.append(x.id)
        logging.debug('g_ids: %s' % g_ids)

...
...
...
```

When I enter a pr_name in the form and submit, the view enters the first if statement prints out 'hello1' and 'hello2' in the console but skips the 'hello3' and skips the second if statement and skips ahead to `secondQuery = secondQuery.replace(')(', ') AND (')`

The debug output is:

```
DEBUG hello1
DEBUG hello2
```

And the error is:

```
UnboundLocalError at /search/
local variable 'secondQuery' referenced before assignment

Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File ".../views.py" in search
  209.          secondQuery = secondQuery.replace(')(', ') AND (')

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /search/
Exception Value: local variable 'secondQuery' referenced before assignment
```

Expected output:

```
DEBUG hello1
DEBUG hello2
DEBUG hello3
DEBUG First query: SELECT * FROM pr where .... (firstQuery)
DEBUG First query: .....  (p_search_results)
```

Comment: can it be that in your source you have spaces and tabs mixed and the block of code that you think should be executed is actually not executed because it is inside an "if" statement?

Comment: Cool. I have moved this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can it be that in your source you have spaces and tabs mixed and the block of code that you think should be executed is actually not executed because it is inside an "if" statement?